# Javascript confirm box not working properly when calling in code behind using asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have a button, When i clicked on this button some code written for checking and then confirm box should be open after clicked OK then some other code should work else if clicked cancel i want to exit no further action required, so problem is my confirm box show after all code executed but i want in middle of the processing.

sorry for my english.

```
    function CheckData() {
        debugger
        //                var hdnConfirm = document.getElementById("hdnConfirm");
        //                hdnConfirm.Value = confirm('Data already exists for current month. Do you want to replace?');
        var sResult = confirm('Data already exists for current month. Do you want to replace?');
        document.getElementById("<%=hdnConfirm.ClientID %>").value = sResult;
    }




 if (ddlYear.SelectedIndex > 0 && ddlMonth.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string sTableName = string.Empty;
        //transaction for web
        oSqlConnectionWeb = new SqlConnection(GetConnection());
        oSqlConnectionWeb.Open();
        oSqlTransactionWeb = oSqlConnectionWeb.BeginTransaction();
        sConnection = GetConnection();

        dtData = new DataTable();
        dtData = Con.GetDataTable("select * from ReimSlip_t where year+month = '" + ddlYear.SelectedValue + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + "'");
        if (dtData.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            sTableName = "ReimSlip_t";
        }
        else
        {
            dtData = new DataTable();
            dtData = Con.GetDataTable("select * from yr_ReimSlip_t where year+month = '" + ddlYear.SelectedValue + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + "'");
            if (dtData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                sTableName = "yr_ReimSlip_t";
            }
        }

        dtLocal = Con.GetDataTable("select * from " + sTableName + " where year+month = '" + oModule.CurrentYearReim + oModule.CurrentMonthReim + "'");
        if (dtLocal.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            AlterTable("ReimSlip_t", sConnection, "WEB");
            // Con.Execute("Delete from " + sTableName + " where year+month = '" + oModule.CurrentYearReim + oModule.CurrentMonthReim + "' ");

            iCount = Con.GetCount("select count(*) from ReimSlip_t where year+month = '" + ddlYear.SelectedValue + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + "'", oSqlConnectionWeb, oSqlTransactionWeb);
           // if (iCount > 0)
           // {
                if (ddlYear.SelectedValue == oModule.CurrentYearReim && ddlMonth.SelectedValue == oModule.CurrentMonthReim)
                {//yes or no
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "confirm", "CheckData();", true);
                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$('#myModal').modal();", true);

                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data already exists for current month. You are not authorised to changed the data.');", true);
                }
           // }


            dtWeb = new DataTable();
            dtWeb = Con.GetDataTable("select column_name From information_schema.columns where table_name = 'ReimSlip_t'", oSqlConnectionWeb, oSqlTransactionWeb);
            iCount = dataTransfer(dtLocal, dtWeb, sTableName, oSqlConnectionWeb, oSqlTransactionWeb);
            if (iCount == 1)
            {
                iCount = Con.GetCount("select count(*) from " + sTableName + " where year+month = '" + oModule.CurrentYearReim + oModule.CurrentMonthReim + "'", oSqlConnectionWeb, oSqlTransactionWeb);

                if (iCount == dtLocal.Rows.Count)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data uploaded successfully.');", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data not uploaded. Try again.');", true);
                }
            }
            else if (iCount != 1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data not uploaded. Try again.');", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Data not available for selected year and month.');", true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Select year & month');", true);
    }
```

Comment: What about show your code to help others to be able to determine what the problem is!

Comment: I realise English is not your first language, but could you please at least try to write in separate sentences? I'm sure your own language also uses separate sentences, not one long continuous river of words. It is very hard to read and understand when it is all one big long sentence. Actually though, when you write requirements for your program it is usually better to use lists instead of continuous text, anyway.

Comment: Another thing: if you do not show the code you have written, then obviously we cannot help you to fix it. No-one can fix invisible problems with invisible code!

Comment: Thanks for the update. So... "my confirm box show after all code executed but i want in middle of the processing.". That is how HTTP works. The browser sends a request to the server, the server runs all of its code, and then returns a response to the browser. So the browser cannot show any messages or anything until it gets the response. And you cannot send more than one response to a single HTTP request. There is not much you can do about this situation without making big changes to the architecture of your application.

Comment: ok got it....I also tried before but working fine because I called through client side and then server side code executed.